# Socket io connection not established with express js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Trying to connect to socket io, but not able to connect

**app.js** file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');
const api = require('./api/api');
var app = express();


const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);


app.set('view engine', 'html');

var subdomain = '';
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.listen(1337, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:1337 ');
});

app.use('/', index);
app.post('/sendMessageToUser' , api.sendMessageToUser);


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have try connecting from POSTMAN and http://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/

Postman gives 404
Error: Unexpected server response: 404
Handshake Details
Status Code: 404 Not Found

Not able to understand why socket io connection not happening. other normal API call working fine.

Its latest version of express js and socket io.

**NOTE : also i have create other project on same level of this using Sails js which is working fine connection to socket.**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using server listen instead of app?

```
server.listen(1337, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:1337 ');
});
```